# Email notify if any one change server file & folder permission

Tags: php, email, permissions

I need to email notify if any one change file & folder permission. Please let me know how to do this in wordpress php?.

Comment: Please go read [ask], and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a script to record current file state, such as permission,for example, the first time you run the script, get the permission like 775, store it in a file;
2. Each time you run the script, check if the permission now differs from which stored last time in that file, if so, email the user;
3. Code as following:

```
$last_permission = file_get_contents("permission.txt");
if(!$last_permission){
    $permission = fileperms("file_to_trace.txt");
}else{
    if($permission != fileperms("file_to_trace.txt"){
        mail("user@user.com", "contents");
    }
}
file_put_contents("file_to_trace.txt", $permission);
```